# How to use POSIX message queues with infinite timeout?

Tags: linux, message-queue

I am trying to send/receive messages without specifying any timeout. So, I need an infinite timeout. VxWorks provides `WAIT_FOREVER`, when it is supposed not to limit the timeout. But in Linux that is not available. Which value should be given for defining `MQ_WAIT_FOREVER`?

- define  MQ_WAIT_FOREVER ???
- clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &currenttime);
- /* Calculate the time out value for sending */

  abs_timeout.tv_sec = currenttime.tv_sec + (MQ_WAIT_FOREVER / 1000000);

  abs_timeout.tv_nsec = currenttime.tv_nsec + (MQ_WAIT_FOREVER / 1000);

Thanks a lot in advance!

Gökce

Comment: By default, `mq_send` blocks until there is queue space, and `mq_receive` blocks until there is something to receive (assuming O_NONBLOCK is not set). What do you need that this doesn't provide?

Comment: Post the code that's giving you the problem.